# AUI input onchange detection doesn't work

Tags: javascript, liferay-6, liferay-aui

I am using liferay 6.1.
My JSP has input text. I am writing value on the input text and want to pass that value to the Portlet Controller. But the action is not sent to controller.

JSP Code

```
 <form:input type="text"  name="id" path="id" onchange="" onkeydown=""/>
<aui:script use="event, node">
        AUI().ready('liferay-portlet-url','node',function(A){
            var actionURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createActionURL();
            actionURL.setWindowState("<%=LiferayWindowState.NORMAL.toString() %>");
            actionURL.setPortletMode("<%=LiferayPortletMode.VIEW %>");
            actionURL.setParameter("param","This value comes from Javascript");
            actionURL.setParameter("javax.portlet.action","actionMethodByJavaApi");

            A.one("#id").set('onchange', actionURL.toString());
            A.on("change",function(e){
            var idSelect=  A.one("#id").val();
                 }); 

        });
</aui:script>
```

In the controller

```
@ProcessAction(name="actionMethodByJavaApi")
    public void renderDOB(BindingResult bndingResult, ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response, SessionStatus sessionStatus, Model model)
            throws SystemException, IOException, PortalException, AddressException {
        logger.info("DOB Action");
//      String sampleParam = ParamUtil.get(request, "param", "defaultValue");
//      logger.info("Sample Param is ::"+sampleParam);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you must declare your form  with the AUI tag, example :

```
<aui:form>
<aui:fieldset>
    <aui:input name="verb" id="verb" type="text">
        <aui:validator name="required"/>
    </aui:input>
    <aui:button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" value="Generate"/>
</aui:fieldset>
```

Clearly what you want is an Ajax call / call from javascript,

you can check this tutorial http://www.opensource-techblog.com/2015/07/aui-ajax-in-liferay-portlet.html
it's expose a resource to be used in your Ajax call.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, itried but nothing happen

Comment: Hi Jam, i have updated my answer, to include how to ajax or do a call from javascript, could you please use it and test.